# Work done by massless spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, spring

Since net force on a massless spring is zero, work done on a spring should be zero, according to elementary work done $F \cdot dr$ since
$F= 0$. Then why do we calculate it to be $\frac {kx²}{2}$?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> Since net force on a massless spring is zero, work done on a spring
> should be zero

I think you may be confused on concepts involving springs. You may be thinking the net force on the spring is zero because, per Newton's second law, if $F_{net}=ma$ and if $m=0$ than $F_{net}$ must be zero. But the forces we normally deal with on a spring are not forces that cause the spring to accelerate, but rather forces that can compress or extend a spring giving the spring elastic potential energy of $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$, where $x$ is the displacement of the spring from its relaxed position, and where the mass of the spring is generally ignored.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But same force does Work on the spring which acts on spring .

Comment: Please clarify it a bit more

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. Let's start with you explaining to me why you think the force on the spring is zero?

Comment: Because mass of the spring is assumed to be zero therefore Net Force on Spring should be 0 . If the net Force on the spring is 0 then Work done on the spring i.e F. dr  ( where F is the Force acting on the spring ) = 0  as F comes out to be 0 from m=0 ( in ma )

Comment: It would be very kind of you if you help me

Comment: @CHINMAYCHETAN Are you saying the force must be zero on a massless spring because of the equation $F=ma$?

Comment: Yes @ Bob D that is what I am trying to say

Answer (score 1):

For a massless spring the net force on the spring is zero, and there in no work done on the spring.  But, the spring can do work on another body.  See the example below; the **spring does work on mass $m$**, but for a **massless spring there is no work done on the spring**.  Note: there is a force from the wall on the spring in addition to the force from mass m on the spring, and for a massless spring these two forces sum vectorially to zero.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Suppose two children push with equal and opposite forces on opposite sides of a roundabout. The net force on the roundabout is zero (we know this because its centre of mass does not move). But the energy of the roundabout changes because it gains angular momentum. Where does this energy come from ?

This example shows that just because the net force on an object is zero, this does not mean that the individual forces on the object do no work.

Comment: I don’t think your analogy quite fits. The net force is zero but the net torque is not. The net torque does rotational work giving the roundabout rotational kinetic energy and angular momentum

Comment: @BobD I agree its not an exact analogy. But they key point is that $\Sigma \vec F . \Delta \vec r$ can be non-zero even if $\Sigma \vec F$ is zero.

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding is correct, you should think of the massless spring as an internal spring force between it's edges rather than an actual reactive object.

This way , it is clear there should be no work done **on** the spring (as you remarked) or field since it is not an actual object but this internal force (the spring's) is clearly applied on the "spring"'s edges which is the source of the work done **by** the "spring".

If you want to add mass to the spring or perhaps look at it as a body of it's own you can say that the spring is composed of spaced point masses(or massless points in the ideal case) with ideal spring internal forces applied on them thus thinking of the spring as an internal force more than an actual body.